# dircolors on zsh: Unrecognized keywords: MULTIHARDLINK, RESET & CAPABILITY

Tags: shell, zsh, colors

I am trying to get the [solarized](https://github.com/altercation/solarized) color theme to work in my terminal. I read the instructions [here](http://michaelheap.com/getting-solarized-working-on-ubuntu/) but I get the following dircolors error:

```
dircolors: `/home/avazquez/.dircolors_zsh':90: unrecognized keyword RESET
dircolors: `/home/avazquez/.dircolors_zsh':94: unrecognized keyword MULTIHARDLINK
dircolors: `/home/avazquez/.dircolors_zsh':103: unrecognized keyword CAPABILITY
```

when running:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
fi
```

from my `.zshrc` in zsh (latest version) (which I remotely access `ssh -X` from `gnome-terminal` in Ubuntu).

The path to the `.dircolors` file in question is [here](https://raw.github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized/master/dircolors.256dark) and the troubling lines seem to be some of the special files definitions:

```
## Special files

NORMAL 00;38;5;244 # no color code at all
#FILE 00 # regular file: use no color at all
RESET 0 # reset to "normal" color
DIR 00;38;5;33 # directory 01;34
LINK 01;38;5;37 # symbolic link. (If you set this to 'target' instead of a
 # numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.)
MULTIHARDLINK 00 # regular file with more than one link
FIFO 48;5;230;38;5;136;01 # pipe
SOCK 48;5;230;38;5;136;01 # socket
DOOR 48;5;230;38;5;136;01 # door
BLK 48;5;230;38;5;244;01 # block device driver
CHR 48;5;230;38;5;244;01 # character device driver
ORPHAN 48;5;235;38;5;160 # symlink to nonexistent file, or non-stat'able file
SETUID 48;5;160;38;5;230 # file that is setuid (u+s)
SETGID 48;5;136;38;5;230 # file that is setgid (g+s)
CAPABILITY 30;41 # file with capability
STICKY_OTHER_WRITABLE 48;5;64;38;5;230 # dir that is sticky and other-writable (+t,o+w)
OTHER_WRITABLE 48;5;235;38;5;33 # dir that is other-writable (o+w) and not sticky
STICKY 48;5;33;38;5;230 # dir with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
# This is for files with execute permission:
EXEC 01;38;5;64
```

Comment: I made an ambitious attempt to make sense of `dircolors`. While it is not an answer to your question, it might interest you to check it [out](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/scripts/cols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has little to do with `zsh`. `zsh` supports coloured completion like GNU `ls` does (with things like *blue* for directories, *green* for executables...), and it supports the same configuration directives as GNU `ls` does.

GNU `ls` colour configuration is done via the `LS_COLORS` environment variable. When that variable contains `ln=01;36`, that means that symbolik links are to be rendered in *bold cyan* (`36` being the ANSI colour code for foreground cyan and `01` being bold).

In `zsh`, you can do the same with:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors 'ln=01;36'
```

And actually you generally configure `zsh` coloured completion with:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

So `zsh` colours completions the same way GNU ls does.

To make it easier writing the content of the `LS_COLORS` variable, GNU `ls` comes with the `dircolors` command. That command takes as input a configuration file with a more verbose content (as configuration files don't have space constraints like environment variables have) and generates the corresponding content of the `LS_COLORS` variable suitable for your terminal.

Above we have:

```
LINK 01;38;5;37
```

`01` is still bold, but `38;5;37` is the specification for extended colour modes for terminals like `xterm` that support 88 or 256 colours.

That's foreground colour 37 which is some shade of cyan (`rgb:00/af/af`) slightly darker than the default colour for the ANSI colour 6 (`cyan3` at least with my `xterm`, which here is `rgb:00/cd/cd`).

```
~$ tput setaf 37 | sed l
\033[38;5;37m$
```

When passed through `dircolors`, that becomes `ln=38;5;37`.

There's also `MULTIHARDLINK 00` which says that files with more than one hard link are to be rendered with the default colour. That would translate to `mh=00` in `$LS_COLORS`.

However, that's been introduced in a relatively recent version of `ls`/`dircolors`. It used to be `HARDLINK`/`hl`, but was renamed to `MULTIHARDLINK`/`mh` in coreutils 7.5 in 2009 as that was a more correct choice of wording.

It seems that you have an older version of `dircolors`. Note that `zsh` supports neither `hl` nor `mh` (though it wouldn't complain, just ignore it), and because it's just set to the default colours, you might as well remove that line.

`RESET`/`rs` was added in coreutils 6.11, and is not supported by `zsh` either.

`CAPABILITY`/`ca` was added in coreutils 7.0 and is not supported by `zsh` either.

There are probably more of those not supported by `zsh` (See `info zsh 'The zsh/complist Module'` for details), but again, `zsh` just ignores what it doesn't support.

The errors you get there are from `dircolors`. It just means that whoever wrote that `dircolors` file had a newer version of coreutils (the GNU suite of utilities including `ls` and `dircolors`) than you have. Just remove the lines that are not supported in that file.

Comment: Thanks @Stephane. This is so helpful. What is the difference between the two `zstyle completion` lines? I think I understand the first one as saying "use this color for sym links", but what about the second one? Also, what does completion have to do with the colors that `ls` uses to display files? I understood most of your thread, but there are few things that are not still clear to me.

Comment: OK I think I got it, you mean that zsh also supports colors for completing files and directories, and that it also supports a syntax similar to that of `dircolors` (as in your first zstyle example). The second `zstyle` example tells zsh to use whatever definitions present in `LS_COLORS` correct?

Answer (score 0):

In order for `zsh` to work you MUST ADD :

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

I also have some stuff on github with a [`.zshrc` example](https://github.com/blackmirroxx/dircolors-solarized)